# объясните YII_ENV и YII_DEBUG в yii2

Tags: yii2

Прошу объяснить следующие вещи, связанные с этим кодом в Yii2 advanced:

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true); 
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');​
```

1. `defined` проверяет существование и наличие значения указанной константы. 
   Вопрос 1: Как же она может быть в наличии или быть заданной, если она задаётся далее в этой же строке кода? `defined('YII_DEBUG')` всегда даёт `false`
2. В строке кода определяется значение для контстанты `YII_ENV` в `dev`: `define('YII_ENV', 'dev')`. При этом документация даёт такое пояснение:

> dev: окружение development, т.е. режим для разработки. Константа
>   YII_ENV_DEV установлена в true.

Вопрос 2а: т.е. `YII_ENV = 'dev'` для того чтобы `YII_ENV_DEV = true`? Зачем этот танец с бубном, если можно просто написать `const YII_ENV_DEV = true;`?

Вопрос 2б: когда `define('YII_ENV', 'dev')`, предположительно, что `'YII_ENV_PROD' = false` и `'YII_ENV_TEST' = false`. Где это определяется?

3. Чем отличается режим режим, включаемый константой `YII_ENV_TEST` от режима `YII_ENV_DEV`?
4. Верно ли то, что сначала проверился указанный код в common/main-local.php, а потом переопределился, если есть в frontend/main-local.php и backend/main-local.php?
5. Почему на локали вот этот код

   ```
   <?= '<pre>YII_DEBUG'.var_dump(YII_DEBUG).'</pre>' ?>
   <?= '<pre>YII_ENV'.var_dump(YII_ENV).'</pre>' ?>
   <?= '<pre>YII_ENV_PROD-'.var_dump(YII_ENV_PROD).'</pre>' ?>
   <?= '<pre>YII_ENV_DEV-'.var_dump(YII_ENV_DEV).'</pre>' ?>
   <?= '<pre>YII_ENV_TEST-'.var_dump(YII_ENV_TEST).'</pre>' ?>
   ```

выводит

```
YII_DEBUG     bool(false)
YII_ENV       string(4) "prod"   
YII_ENV_PROD- bool(true)  
YII_ENV_DEV-  bool(false) 
YII_ENV_TEST- bool(false)
```

независимо от того, что укажешь в

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true); 
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');​
```

6. объясните логику создания окружений. Зачем нужны вообще эта константа YII_ENV, если наличие файлов main.php и main-local.php, (аналогично с params) в папках common, frontend и backend как раз  и обеспечивает разные конфигурации для окружений. Зачем нужно писать `if (YII_ENV_DEV)` , если само существование файлов ...-local.php говорит о том, что в них должна быть конфигурация локали, а не в них - конфигурация продакшена.

Буду благодарен, если будете нумеровать ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `YII_DEBUG` может быть установлена ранее и тогда будет использовано ее значение. Если эта константа не установлена, то устанавливается в true.
2. Танец с бубном скорее всего необходим для каки-то внутренних обработок событий, либо для более простого внедрения какой-то логики в существующий код (возможно чужой код). `YII_ENV_PROD` и `YII_ENV_TEST` определяются в `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php`
3. Режим разработки может много чем отличаться от режима тестирования. Например, для тестирования мы можем использовать другую базу данных или отключать работу со сторонними компонентами. Например для прогонки тестов есть смысл отключить работу с сервисом по отправке смс (они платные).
4. Все верно. В директории `common` храним конфиги для всего проекта. Например подключение к БД будет одинаковое для фронта и админки, а для каждого приложения некоторые настройки надо переопределить. Например, разные режимы логирования и разные таргеты.
5. Потому что константы установлены ранее и выражение после `or` не выполняется.
6. Окружения устанавливаются при выполнении файла `init`, это сделано для того, чтобы на любой машине можно было развернуть приложение в любом окружении.

Вообще эта концепция с `-local.php` не очень удобная (при этом она вполне рабочая) и мы стараемся от нее уходить. Например при использовании приложения в kubernetes не очень практично работать с локальными конфигами. Проще через .env